# Fonts look differently by browser

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

I'm using a font to apply icons on my form inputs.

Here is the CSS:

```
// Import the fonts
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Payline Icons';
  src: url('@{imagesUrl}/icons/icons.eot');
  src: url('@{imagesUrl}/icons/icons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    //url('@{imagesUrl}/icons/icon_monext.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('@{imagesUrl}/icons/icons.woff') format('woff'),
  url('@{imagesUrl}/icons/icons.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('@{imagesUrl}/icons/icons.svg#monexticons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}

[class*="pl-icon-"] {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Payline Icons' !important;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-size: 25px !important;// This doesn't act the same on every browser, at all!
}

// Individual icons
.pl-icon-credit-card {
  &:before { content: "\E600"; }
}
.pl-icon-compte {
  &:before { content: "\E601"; }
}
.pl-icon-cvv {
  &:before { content: "\E602"; }
}
.pl-icon-date-naissance {
  &:before { content: "\E603"; }
}
.pl-icon-date {
  &:before { content: "\E604"; }
}
.pl-icon-optioncredit{
  &:before { content: "\E605"; }
}
.pl-icon-user {
  &:before { content: "\E606"; }
}
```

Here is the HTML of a single input:

```
<div class="pl-input-group-container">
    <div class="pl-input-group pl-paymentMethod-input-container">
        <input id="pl-paymentMethod-cards_11-expirationDate" class="pl-input" type="tel" placeholder="•• / ••" value="">
        <span id="pl-paymentMethod-cards_11-feedbackExpirationDate" class="pl-glyphicon pl-input-feedback pl-glyphicon-warning-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="pl-form-control-addon pl-icon-date"></span>
</div>
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Firefox]Firefox
[image: Chrome]Chrome
[image: IE 8]IE 8

I'm trying to get the same look on all major browser (I don't really care if it's ugly in IE8... So FF and Chrome mostly)

I tried to change the property `font-size` but it doesn't has the same size for every browser. I'm not a designer at all and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. i'd mostly need to have them all vertically aligned with the input, even if it's not exactly the same size.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using normalize.css? That could be a place to start.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is that you will need to add a CSS reset for font properties, so they work similarly in most browses. Try Eric Meyer’s CSS reset as a test.

Comment: Smart, but I can't use normalize.css since I'm writing a widget which will be included in other people's website and I don't want that adding my widget would change the way their website behave, but it's a place to start, I think I can basically take the rules related to the fonts in normalize.css and apply them one by one to make sure they're applied only to my widget.

Comment: so normalize things yourself by setting all the root properties of your widget based on `rem` units at the root of your widget, and percentages deeper into your content.

Comment: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Comment: Actually, my main issue was totally unrelated. It was because I was using `[class*="pl-icon-"] {&::first-letter {font-size: 120%;}}` someplace else which messed up totally the display on a specific view but I didn't realisez that until this morning. I stopped using `first-letter` to use font-size directly instead which works correctly on all browsers. Thanks for the help!